# Can Asp.net Core automatically detect View changes in a custom directory?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have got a custom location configured for some views. e.g. `/MyCustom/Views/Index.cshtml`. The application can correctly find the views from `/MyCustom/Views` folder using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36772778/1593334.

The only issue is that I have to build the application each time I change a view to reflect the changes in the browser. Is there a way to make the asp.net automatically detect these changes ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool called `dotnet watch`.

> dotnet watch is a development time tool that runs a dotnet command when source files change. It can be used to compile, run tests, or publish when code changes.

Basically, you add the `Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools` NuGet package to the `tools` section of your `project.json` and run the application using `dotnet watch`.

Here you can find [the command arguments for running `dotnet watch`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/dotnet-watch.html#running-dotnet-commands-using-dotnet-watch).

Then, while the application is running with `dotnet watch`, simply modify the source code of the application. The watcher will detect the change, recompile and rerun the application.

Best regards!