# ASP.NET Core 2.0 ViewLocation - How to add another location that is in an Area

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have added an Area to my project called  /Areas/Views/Shared 
(FYI...This is in addition to the default of Views/Shared)

I believe that I added it correctly to  services in Startup (Added after services.AddMvc)

```
Startup.cs
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/Views/Shared/" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension));
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'Areas/Views/Shared/_foo' was not found. 
The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/_foo.cshtml
```

If _foo.cshtml did not exist then I would expect the exception to read as follows:

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'Areas/Views/Shared/_foo' was not found. 
The following locations were searched:
/Views/Shared/_foo.cshtml
/Areas/Views/Shared/_foo.cshtml
```

I read a couple of posts such as the item below...but I am stuck for the moment

[How to specify the view location in asp.net core mvc when using custom locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747293/how-to-specify-the-view-location-in-asp-net-core-mvc-when-using-custom-locations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more playing around I found the solution...I was missing {0}

```
Startup.cs
     services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension));
```