# Set Hangfire UI as Default Page ASPNET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, hangfire

I have a simple ASPNET core MVC out of the box template app.  I installed the Hangfire nuget packages for the purpose hosting the UI.  This app will not be a Hangfire client or server, just a single app for people to see the status of their jobs.

I want to set the default page to the Hangfire dashboard of the app.  There will two screens - the login and the dashboard.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460010/how-do-i-set-a-default-home-page-in-asp-net-core-2) answer provided guidance on how to do it with pages actually referenced in the app - but it does not work when I set it with "/hangfire". I end up getting an exception thrown because the "hangfire" page does not exist.

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("hangfire", "/hangfire");
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

The exception makes sense - but I am not sure how to configure the default route as the hangfire dashboard.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#change-url-mapping

Comment: No.  that allows you to customize either the route the dashboard is (default /hangfire) or to specify a different path for the back to site link.  What I am looking for is for the AspNetCore app to set the default route of /hangfire.  So when someone types http://host.com - the default page is the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

on your launchSettings.json

you just need add the next key/value: "launchUrl": "hangfire"

```
"MyApp.Dashboard": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "hangfire",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:1234;http://localhost:4321",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

I hope this helps