# Asp.Net core 2.0 MVC anchor tag helper not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am trying to create a demo page, and can't solve the next problem, and I tried everything what I found on the web.
I have an anchor tag with tag helper:

```
<a class="menu-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Telefon" asp-action="Index">Telefonok</a>
```

I also added a **_ViewImports.cshtml** and in it I added as I saw in the net
**@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"**, but I still got an error: **The name 'addTagHelper' does not exist in the current context**

What did I wrong?!

Comment: I agree with [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49629874/7311767). Including the ViewImports.cshtml file in the Views folder, but specifically having the TagHelpers Mark referred to addressed my issue. I was lazy and just copied the file. Depending on what you need, you could cull it down.

Answer (score 8):

There are two _ViewImports.cshtml, you probably need the one located in the Views Folder.

In my project I have a another one under Views/Manage

Also the line required should be as follows:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

This I believe means it will include all of the Tag Helpers in the namespace.

Note the use of the Asterix (*)

Comment: In our newly generated project, _Layout and _ViewImports have not even been craeted and had to create it manually `Add > New Item > Text File > /Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`. As a reference: 
 https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewimports

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure the following things are in place:

1. Make sure you create the `_ViewImports.cshtml` in the right location/directory either at the root level of Views directory or inside any view folder as per your requirement. See the below snip. It should be something like this..

[image]

2. To use Tag Helpers in your .NET Core application, you need to define the directive **'@addTagHelper'** inside the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file along with the assembly name. Here is the assembly name **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers**. So now your file will look something like this:

   `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

The Asterisk(*) sign here means you want to include all the tag helpers that is there inside the assembly.

**NOTE:** This is embarrassing. The mistake that I made was really silly & ridiculous which made me scratch my head a lot at first. Just so no one does the same thing, be very careful while writing down the assembly name. Notice the casing in Mvc.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers => ✔
Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC.TagHelpers => ❌
```