# ASP.Net Core Change Default Views Folder Location

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I'm trying to change the default views location so the following works:

```
[Route("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The location of where I want the views is /MVC/Views/ControllerName/Index(MethodName)

I've attempt by adding the following to Startup => ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection)

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
});
```

The following works but I would prefer for it to default to the correct path

```
return View("/MVC/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
```

Comment: are you configuring it after services.AddMvc() ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901806/8471295) answer:

From .Net-Core v2.0 upwards you can use `ViewLocationFormats` and `AreaViewLocationFormats` in RazorViewEngineOptions to modify the View look-up.

The option you are looking for is `ViewLocationFormats` since you're not using View Areas.

Your Solution would be along these lines:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/MVC/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/MVC/Views/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    });
```

The last line is only needed if you have the shared Layouts and Paritals at that location and not in the Standard Folder.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, if anyone is looking for changing the default view folder location for `Areas` (like me), here is the solution:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Clear();
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats
        .Add($"/Path/To/Views/{{1}}/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
    options.AreaViewLocationFormats
        .Add($"/Path/To/Views/Shared/{{0}}{RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension}");
});
```