# Need to pass parameter to multiple Partial Views on single view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying very hard to rewrite this question better than my previous effort which received no responses. Even though I’m nearly done with this application, I am still a relative newbie at programming and it seems like one challenge just leads to another. I have looked at many posts related to the problem of passing a parameter to several Partial Views in a single view page. So let’s take this in order from the `AlertPick.cshtml` page where the user chooses one of three  `Alert_Identifier/SelectedAlertIndex`  parameters from the application database. I’m only showing the @model and Select Tag Form.

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.EdxlCapMessageViewModel
@{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>

    <form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="PickAlert" method="post">
        <select class="cap_select" id="cap_select" style="width:100%;max-width:95%;"
        asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="PickAlert" value="Pick Alert to Assemble EDXL-Cap Message" />
    </form>
}
```

This takes the user to the`PickAlert.cshtml` page, a table of five rows where the first four rows are the Data Categories of the application: Alert, Info, Area and Resource each with the `Alert_Identifier` repeated as a reminder in a text box followed by its own submit button named `Check Alert, Check Info, Check Area, and Check Resource`, respectively. These submit buttons take the user to a `_DetailsAlert.cshtml, _DetailsInfo.cshtml, _DetailsArea.cshtml, and _DetailsResource.cshtml` pages and they work correctly, with the data item names and values from the record that matches the `Alert_Identifier`. The fifth row repeats the Identifier and its button reads `Add All`, to assemble the whole set together for review and takes the user to the`_Assemble.cshtml` page below, where the individual data categories are correctly assembled with the data item names, but lack the correct data values that match the record that corresponds to the `Alert_Identifier`. I’m thinking that I need to add a third parameter for the `SelectedAlertIndex` or `Alert_Identifier` to each of the `@Html.Partial(...)` Views, but I haven’t found the correct form/syntax for that, and If someone could supply that  or point me to an example similar enough to this, I would deeply appreciate it.

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.EdxlCapMessageViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/capv1_2_refimp.css" />
    <title>Assembled EDXL-CAP Message</title>
</head>

<h4>Assemble EDXL-CAP Message</h4>

<!-- DetailsAlert -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert", Model.Alert)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsAlert -->

<!-- DetailsInfo -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsInfo", Model.Info)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsInfo -->

<!-- DetailsArea -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsArea", Model.Area)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsArea -->

<!-- DetailsResource -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsResource", Model.Resource)
</div>
<!-- End of DetailsResource -->
```

Responding to first comment below, I'm showing the `InfosController.cs` code for `_DetailsInfo(int? id)` the controller action for the Info Data Category. It is virtually identical for each of the data categories except that the line `... .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.InfoIndex == id);` becomes `....SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AlertIndex == id); and the method itself becomes`_DetailsAlert(int? id).

```
// GET: Infos/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> _DetailsInfo(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var info = await _context.Info
            //.Include(e => e.Elements)
            //    .ThenInclude(d => d.DataCategory)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.InfoIndex == id);

        if (info == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(info);
    }
```

PickAlert method from AlertsController follows:

```
public IActionResult PickAlert(Alert obj, int? SelectedAlertIndex)
    {
        if (SelectedAlertIndex.HasValue)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Alert loaded successfully";
        }
        return View(_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));
    }
```

Comment: It's not very clear. But your View looks sensible, whatever logic you think you are missing should be in the Controller. The (partial) Views shouldn't do anything more complex than maybe a `if(Model.SubViewModel != null) ...`

Comment: Thanks @ Henk Holterman. I added the `_DetailsInfo(int? id)` controller action to the end of the question for one of the four data categories to see if that makes it any more clear.

Comment: Do you mean that you have to pass an identifier to your partial view(s)  SelectedAlertIndex along with the model you are passing like `Model.Alert` `Model.Resource` etc ?

Comment: @PM Yes, I think so. As it is, the `_Assemble.cshtml` page displays all four `_DetailsXXX` partial views but without data values for the named data items. It appears to be missing `SelectedAlertIndex, SelectedInfoIndex, SelectedAreaIndex and SelectedResourceIndex` parameters respectively, that collectively constitute the complete Emergency Data Exchange Language Common Alerting Protocol (EDXL-CAP) message.

Comment: if this is .net core, look into using injection

Comment: But that controller isn't used here, is it? You should look into ViewModels.

Comment: Is `Model.Info` an info object or an Id ?

Comment: `Model.Info` is an info object like Alert, Area and Resource are objects of their models. They produce the data item names in the `_DetailsXXXX()` views and partial views. The individual view pages have the correct data values. The composite page has names with no values, hence my thought that I need the SelectedCategoryIndex values. And I'm using ViewModels.

Comment: @Neville Nazerane, this is an ASP.NET Core MVC Visual Studio Project. Wondering what aspect of dependency injection you think I should look into? It's interesting to me at this point because this project is nearing completion, but I have follow-on projects with similar structure, so such a design decision might be helpful.

Comment: The controller of interest is the one that fills a EdxlCapMessageViewModel. I don't get the questions about 'Id', the _DetailsInfo(int? id) action won't be called for a Partial View. Verify with the debugger.

Comment: Thanks @bommelding your question nudged me to notice that I had, in fact,neglected to include PickAlert() method in EdxlCapMessageViewModelsController. However, adding that didn't solve the problem. I checked and `_DetailsInfo(int? id)` isn't called for the partial view though it is called for the single view. An answer that fills in the partial views on the composite page would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Your assembled View looks Ok, the controller that calls it should set the .Alert, .Info and .Area properties.  It should have all the Ids to do that. You didn't post or name that controller, that makes  a more detailed answer difficult.

Comment: to pass additional data into partial views, viewbag is a good solution. you can also consider passing the entire model to the partial view

Comment: regarding the injections i was talking about, i was under the impression that you are trying to pass around data to multiple views. if that is the case i can show you some examples.

Comment: @Neville Nazerane I am specifically passing the `SelectedAlertIndex` that corresponds to the `Alert_Identifier` of a record in the application db. That int is passed to each of four partial views that represent the four data categories of the application. I'd be happy to look at examples since I'm currently stuck.

Comment: I am at https://github.com/rexbroo on GitHub and I have put the latest updates from this question into a new branch of  repositories: edxl_cap_v1_2-VS4Win (for Windows) and ...-VS4Mac (for Mac). The new branch in either platform repository is named Assemble-Review-Approve for the remaining pages/functions. We're working on Assemble. I added a dump of the mysql database for both platforms in the repository edxl_cap_v1_2.sql-mysql-VisualStudio with today's date 20180928

Comment: Hi @bommelding, I didn't fully read your comment from Sept. 27 saying that the controller for the `_Assemble.cshtml` should set the .Alert, .Info and .Area properties. I kept that controller minimal: `public IActionResult _Assemble()
        {
            return View(new EdxlCapMessageViewModel());
        }`
so, if you have the time show me how it should specify those properties, it might be key. Key property is `Alert_Identifier` which can be assigned to `AlertIndex, InfoIndex, AreaIndex and ResourceIndex` respectively as it speciifies which record from the db is needed for display.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got the requirement correctly, but I think you have to create another model for all 4 partial views, e.g. for Alert, create a new model

```
class AlertModel:EdxlCapMessageViewModel
{
  int SelectedAlertIndex {get;set;}
}
```

And then your view would look like:

```
<!-- DetailsAlert -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    @Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert",new AlertModel { Alert = Model.Alert,
                                                   SelectedAlertIndex = <ID SOMEHOW>
                                                 });
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @PM, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm trying @PM, but I haven't figured out the <ID SOMEHOW> yet. Didn't want to give the impression I was ignoring anyone even if I don't get back quickly. I think this is the right track and I wonder if the answer is in the controller action `... .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.InfoIndex == id);` I tried `id` and Intellisense says `id does not exist in current context.`

Comment: I am still not clear I think. Which ID do you want to pass to those partial views? Do you have that ID in your model `EdxlCapMessageViewModel` ? I guess not, but then as per your business logic, who has that ID? your view will decide it or your controller knows it by some calculation?

Comment: The id that I want to pass into each of the four partial views comes from the dropdownlist form in the first code block in the question above from the line `asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="Model.Alert_Identifiers">` Alert_Identifiers are long guid strings, but the value that comes from this selection is the AlertIndex int for the record in the db that contains that unique Alert_Identifier. `That is the SelectedAlertIndex` You can see the page generated by the dropdownlist submit at starbourne.com/img/PickAlert.cshtml.jpg.

Comment: EdxlCapMessageViewmodel does not have this ID, except for AlertIndex. Each of the first four rows display the correct`_DetailsXXXX/X` single view page with correct values for that data category. See example starbourne.com/img/_DetailsAlert.cshtml.jpg. We’re trying to get the fifth row which displays all four _DetailsXXX pages together in a single view to work. As of now there are no values for the data items but otherwise the page is ok. Note please that I will probably remove this comment as soon as I get this working, but I don’t have sufficient reputation points to embed images.

Comment: Sorry for all confusion, hence removed my previous comments. Can you post the code of your method `PickAlert` in `AlertsController` ?

Comment: Added PickAlert() method at end of question above.

Comment: You are getting the value of `SelectedAlertIndex` in your PickAlert() method? if yes, then does your collection `Alert` in _context has any entry with the passed `AlertIndex` ?

Comment: Yes @PM. The four single view pages in PickAlert.cshtml that are the views for the PickAlert() method work correctly. It's only the composite view with 4 partial views that somehow isn't getting `return View(_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex));` correctly.

Comment: Let us consider that your model you are getting from `_context.Alert.Where(<condition>)` is correct. Confirm it with debug placed on it. Once you are sure your model is correct, use another overload of `View`. Use it like:
`return View("Composite.cshtlm",_context.Alert.Where(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex))` Assuming the "Composite.cshtml" is your integrated view.

Comment: I verified that the model  is correct, and I've been trying many variations of your suggestion  but I haven't met success yet. Last thing I tried was creating a PickAlert4() Controller Method with the overload `return View(...)` and corresponding PickAlert4cshtml (composite) View for the overload but I got a 404 when I hit the `Add All` submit button. We need an emoji for crosseyed--me.

Comment: I doubled checked and tried again but still got the 404 result after an initially blank page then clicking the reload button. Strange because the contents of the `_PickAlert4.cshtml` is the same as `_Assemble.cshtml` which displays the four details pages without the data values. Very frustrating.

Comment: That's a bit strange because flow looks normal to me. If you can, share the bare minimal running code, where others can see the issue by running the code, that might help.

Comment: I'll put it up on GitHub tomorrow. I have to start a new branch for this latest update.

Comment: I am at https://github.com/rexbroo on GitHub and I have put the latest updates from this question into a new branch of repositories: edxl_cap_v1_2-VS4Win (for Windows) and ...-VS4Mac (for Mac). The new branch in either platform repository is named Assemble-Review-Approve for the remaining pages/functions. We're working on Assemble. I added a dump of the mysql database for both platforms in the repository edxl_cap_v1_2.sql-mysql-VisualStudio with today's date 20180928

Comment: Hi @PM I neglected to specifically alert you in the comment above, but I wanted to make sure you saw it.

Comment: I looked at location of view, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747293/how-to-specify-the-view-location-in-asp-net-core-mvc-when-using-custom-locations) and added `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
            {    
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Controllers/{1}/Views/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
                o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/Controllers/Shared/Views/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
            });` to my Startup.cs file, but still no values, just names in composite view.

Comment: Actually, after restarting, the composite page threw a 404 Not found error, rather than loading composite details without values. Still Stumped!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, I took the code from the github, but it's not building for me. I am getting too many ambiguous reference issues. Please fix it if you can.

Comment: Thanks @PM. Since it runs for me, I'm not getting those exceptions. I had that issue with duplicated properties of some classes. I fixed fixed them by deleting the least-used or unnecessary properties or any duplicated classes. I should advise you to make sure you download the `Assemble-Review-Approve` branch of either platform. It would help me to know which platform, `...VS4Win` or `...VS4Mac`, so let me know and  I'll compare my working code to that which you downloaded. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi again @PM, Do you have an example for what <ID SOMEHOW> should be? Nothing I've tried has worked. Intellisense seems to want a boolean? Also, if you have cloned the branch of the project, do you still need me to disambiguate items?

Answer (score 0):

In .net core when I need to pass around a lot of data across the views, I usually find it cleanest to use services and DI. First, you can create a class that could store a set of data:

```
class MyDataForViews {
    // the following is an example. You can have any properties
    public string Info { get; set; }

}
```

You now have to add this class as a service. To do so go to your startup class and add the following within the services function:

```
services.AddScoped<MyDataForViews>();
```

Scoped means that the framework will create a new object of `MyDataForViews` for each HTTP request. No matter how many places you "inject" an object of `MyDataForViews`, it would use the same object across the current HTTP request. You can also replace the function with `AddSingleton` if you want to use the same object throughout the web app. The following is how you inject an object into your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    MyDataForViews myData;

    // in controllers injection is done using the constructor 
    public MyController(MyDataForViews MyData) => myData = MyData;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        myData = ....   // assign all required data here
        View();
    }

}
```

Once this is done, instead of passing models to each view, you can inject the data into views using the following:

```
@inject MyDataForViews MyData;
```

Once you use this line on the top of any view, you can use the `MyData` object and there is no need to pass models to each partial view.

Comment: Thanks @Neville Nazerane. This is new to me. Gonna havta study it some.

Comment: Here is a sample using something like this if you want to look into https://github.com/neville-nazerane/docs. The website for the code is docs.nevillenazerane.com

Comment: Thanks @Neville Nazerane Cloned docs. Looks interesting. Will Study. I encourage you to think about putting together a tutorial.

Comment: I was thinking the same. as of now, however, I am caught up setting up these libraries that have been documented on the webpage

Comment: Thanks @Neville Nazerane. I look forward to it.

Comment: for now let me know if you get the injection concept in the docs. else i'll make a separate readme file on that.

Comment: Thanks again @Neville Nazerane. I'm wound up in events this week leading up to the Joint OASIS-HL7 Release of an Emergency Mgt specification EDXL-HAVE-v2.0 at an HL7 event in Baltimore, so I probably won't get back to this until next week, so I'd really appreciate that  README. I basically get dependency injection, but this is a little more complex. </understatement>

Comment: Hi again @Neville Nazerane. I've been studying DI and doing tutorials, and I am getting a grasp of DI for various purposes. However, for this project, I want to use it only for getting the value of `SelectedAlertIndex` which is created when a user makes a selection from a dropdownlist. This equates to your example `MyDataForViews` so if you help me with how to `get` that value. I would deeply appreciate it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more detailed answer, since you've said at softwareengineering.stackexchange.com site that you still need help with this.
Let's first make sure you understand the basics correctly.

When it comes to passing data to the view, each controller in ASP.NET MVC has a property named `ViewData`, which is essentially a dictionary of key-value pairs. The `ViewData` itself has a property called `Model`, and this is what you access in the page using the Razor syntax `@Model`. You can use this property to pass a model that is strongly-typed, to avoid using magic strings for the keys of ViewData.

Note: ViewBag is a dynamic wrapper around the ViewData, so it's essentially the same thing (`ViewBag.SomeProperty` is the same as `ViewData['SomeProperty']`); the use of ViewBag is discouraged, though.

In a controller action when you do something like `return View()`, ASP.NET uses the cshtml page as a template to create actual HTML, and return it as the response to the client (this is all server-side).

There are a few ways to pass data to the view which are equivalent, for example:

```
ViewData.Model = someObject;
return View();
```

is the same as:

```
return View(someObject);   // the View method can accept a model object
```

When it comes to *partial views*, by default, they get passed a *copy* of the parent page `ViewData` (this includes the reference to the `Model`), so *you don't have to do anything special* to pass this data to a partial view (but you can pass data of your choice if you want to).

The select tag helper renders (generates HTML) for the select element with the options specified. This is then sent as HTML to the client. On the client side, when the user clicks the submit button, a POST request is sent to the server, which is ultimately handled by the method `PickAlert` method on the `AlertsController`. If everything is setup correctly, you should get the `SelectedAlertIndex` as the parameter. Note that this is happening back at the server side, and that you now need to again return a page as the response.

You can pick the corresponding `Alert` object from your `_context`. Use the `FirstOrDefault` method for this instead of `Where`, as you only need a single item (convert types for comparison if necessary - e.g., if you have a string, but you are comparing to an int, or something along those lines).

```
var selectedAlert = _context.Alert.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex);
```

Now, all you need to do is set this `selectedAlert` and any other data that you need as a property on your model object (or under some key in ViewData), and render the correct view.

Note that if you just `return View(model)` without specifying the name of the view, the system will look for a view with the same name as your action method (here, PickAlert.cshtml), so use `return View("ViewName", model)` to change that if necessary.

For example, based on the code you've posted in your question, you could do something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PickAlert(int? SelectedAlertIndex)
{
    var model = new EdxlCapMessageViewModel(/* ... params, if any */);

    if (SelectedAlertIndex.HasValue)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Alert loaded successfully";
        var selectedAlert = _context.Alert.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AlertIndex == SelectedAlertIndex);            

        // I added a property to your model to store the alert; 
        // if you already have one, just use that one instead.
        model.SelectedAlert = selectedAlert;    
    }
    return View("YourViewName", model);
}
```

The `YourViewName` should be the parent view that has the partial views in it (the "Assembled EDXL-CAP Message" view, I presume).

BTW, I know that the way the system is passing the parameters to the action methods in a controller may seem a bit like magic, but it's convention-based. In the example above, it works because the parameter is named `SelectedAlertIndex`, and the model object has a property *with the same name* (and because you've specified that property in the select tag helper using `asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex"`). You can also modify the method signature so that it receives the entire model object (assuming that the model class is not too complicated - you can read more about how parameter binding works [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PickAlert(EdxlCapMessageViewModel model)
    {
        // extract the index from model.SelectedAlertIndex
        // you can also pass this same model object to the view 
        // (set some properties first if necessary)
        // ...
    }
```

Now for the partial views. Assuming that you are relying on the default mechanism which passes the parent ViewData to each partial view, you need to modify each partial view so that the code is written under the assumption that you can access the selected alert using `@Model.SelectedAlert` (the property you've set in the PickAlert action).

For example, a here's a simple partial view:

```
<div style="border: solid 1px #000000; padding: 30px; margin: 2px 2px 10px 2px;">
    <p>The selected index is: @Model.SelectedAlert.AlertIndex</p>
</div>
```

Note that I'm just using the same model as in the parent view to access the SelectedAlert object: `@Model.SelectedAlert.AlertIndex`.

Again, when rendering the partial views, if you pass no additional parameters, they'll get a copy of the `ViewData` dictionary, and the same `Model`:

```
@Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert");
```

If you pass something else as the model, e.g., only the selected alert, then you need to change the partial view code accordingly:

```
@Html.Partial("_DetailsAlert", Model.SelectedAlert);
```

```
<div style="border: solid 1px #000000; padding: 30px; margin: 2px 2px 10px 2px;">
    <p>The selected index is: @Model.AlertIndex</p>
</div>
```

Note that now, in the partial view, the local `@Model` refers to what was `@Model.SelectedAlert` in the parent view. (In other words, here `@Model` is of type `Alert`.) This only affects the `ViewData.Model` property; the key-value pairs stored in `ViewData` are still the same as those in the parent view.

Comment: Thanks @Filip Milavanovic Thank you for the detailed answer. I just wanted to say thanks in case I don't get back to this again today. My first attempt didn't work, but I'll keep at it. You've given me plenty to work with.

Comment: Thanks again @Filip Milovanović  When I duped your first `[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PickAlert(int? SelectedAlertIndex)`, in the line: `model.SelectedAlert = selectedAlert;` I had to add `public static implicit operator int(Alert v) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }` to  AlertViewModel.cs. to implicitly convert SelectedAlert to an int. I needed to change `“YourViewName”` to `PickAlert` because that's the view needed. But I got a NotImplementedException from that line in AlertViewModel.cs & cites the line: `model.SelectedAlert = selectedAlert;` from AlertsController.cs.

Comment: I a, also working on an updated question, and I will add a comment to you if I post it.