# Multiple web MVC projects in one SLN and routing to the correct view folder

Tags: asp.net-core

**Background:** I'm working on a project to compare the different ways of building an api alongside the different ways to present views to the client. Namely, comparing a level 2 REST API, a level 3 REST API (with HATEOS), and a GraphQL api.On the client I want to compare a standard MVC web application, a Razor one, and an Angular one. You can see the current state of my project [here](https://github.com/JDillon522/api-exploration). I used a couple of Pluralsight courses to configure identity server. Its nothing special and its mostly a bunch of random features for the sake of learning.

I dont want to duplicate a ton of logic and I enjoy the challenge. So I want to find a way to serve the different projects in the same sln. So far I've configured the authentication, data layer, and server projects.

The server is where the main and startup classes live.

**Question:**  How can I serve views from controllers in different projects. In API. Authentication I want the Login views kept in that project.

I used this SO question to get me pointed in a direction:
[How to specify the view location in asp.net core mvc when using custom locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747293/how-to-specify-the-view-location-in-asp-net-core-mvc-when-using-custom-locations)

In my Startup class I have this:

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => {
            options.ViewLocationFormats.Clear();
            options.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/API.Authentication/Views/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        });
```

When I go to `localhost:8000/login` it errors but it says that its looking in the correct location.

How can I configure to point to multiple folders outside of the Startup Classe's directory?